# Rails partial iframe missing assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, iframe, partial-views, assets

I'm trying to create an iframe that's placed on an other website (not mine) and renders one partial of my site. Everything works well but the content of the iframe (my site) doesn't seem to have any assets included. I'm using Rails 4.0.4. I think it happens because the `application.html.erb` isn't loaded because I'm just rendering a partial.

Here is the iframe code:

```
<iframe src="<%= url_for controller: 'welcome', action: 'iframe' %>" scrollbars="auto" height="480" width="320" name="RiverOfNews"></iframe>
```

And here is the corresponding controller method:

```
def iframe
  load_channels
  render :partial => 'news'
end
```

Comment: When you say assets - do you mean stylesheets and javascripts?
In that case you probably don't want to render just the partial but the view with a special layout containing the "assets" but no other layout elements.

Comment: Yes I mean stylesheets and javascripts. The content of the iframe looks like plain html without anything. Ok that sounds good, how would I do that?

Comment: Why do you want to have your own page inside the iframe? I hoped those times are over now.

Comment: It's a news site which allows clients to embed the "news stream".

Comment: @BroiSatse I can think of many valid reasons for using iframes today. For example - making it easy for other persons to embedd your site. (eg. the embedded twitter feed is an iframe)
LinusAn clearly states that other persons websites are supposed to use this feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your controller would then look something like:

```
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController
  def iframe
    load_channels
    render :partial => "news", :layout => "iframe"
  end
end
```

And then you create a new stripped down layout named "_iframe.html.erb" (or .haml or whatever you use) containing only your assets and the "yield" (easy if you copy your application layout and remove the parts you don't need).

Read up on: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html if needed

Comment: I did as you said and created the "iframe.html.erb" inside the layouts folder but I now get the following error: `Missing partial layouts/iframe with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :jbuilder, :coffee]}.`

Comment: Have you created the file "iframe.html.erb" in the folder "app/views/layouts"?

Comment: Oh sorry - try putting a "_" in front of the file - so _iframe.html.erb

Comment: Yes it works, awesome. Thank you so much! Just out of curiousity, why does need to be named _iframe while application.html.erb doesn't need a _ ?

Comment: Check 3.4.3 Partial Layouts in http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html

Comment: I implemented this solution, but I'm getting an issue with routes.rb. I'm a bit nervous to edit that file without a second opinion. How would you edit routes.rb for this solution?