# How do I load ERB into an iframe?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, iframe

I'm running Ruby on rails and I want to load up an erb file into an iframe. The initial page loading up the iframe works fine with loading up variables, but the iframe doesn't have access to the ruby variables and just prints "Print <%= some-ruby-variable %>".

Webpage loading the iframe

```
<iframe src="../test.html.erb"></iframe>
```

file test.html.erb

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<p>Print <%= some-ruby-variable %></p>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm thinking I'm just doing a file read with this iframe call and I'm bypassing the ruby processing.

How do I tell test.html.erb to evaluate the erb before loading to browser?

Comment: have your tried using an actual route as the source rather than a file? e.g. `src="www.example.com/test"` where test routes through a controller and renders that file.

Comment: Yea I wrote a controller but the routing has me all confused I put the details in another question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54209837/how-do-i-create-a-routes-rb-entry-for-a-controller

Comment: I have to assume you are very new to rails. Maybe try a tutorial to get a better understanding; Michael Hartl's tutorials are excellent (and free) https://www.railstutorial.org/

Answer (score 1):

You can actually render a partial inside the iframe. You  can apply the same result  of this question. [Rails partial iframe missing assets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22810287/rails-partial-iframe-missing-assets). All you have to do is specify the controller name and action inside the iframe tag and render the partial inside the controller action.

Comment: I tried to implement this but I can't get the routes code working to test it. I opened a second question for it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54209837/how-do-i-create-a-routes-rb-entry-for-a-controller